# jQuery on click change css for DIV

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have created 2 buttons SHOW & HIDE. And a `DIV` with content. I when clicked on 1st button content `DIV` should expand width and it will hide the 1st button, at the same time 2nd button will become visible.

When clicked on 2nd button content `DIV` should collapse its width and 2nd button will hide, and 1st button will become visible. But its not working.. help me. I don't have much knowledge of jquery, but I use a bit of it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#seeall2").hide();

    $("#seeall").bind("click",
    function(){
        $("#speakers").animate({width: 880}, 1500);
        $("#seeall").hide(500);
        $("#seeall2").show(500);
    });

    $("#seeall2").bind("click",
    function(){
        $("#speakers").animate({width: 410}, 1500);
        $("#seeall").show(500);
        $("#seeall2").hide(500);
    });
});
```

This is my HTML :

```
<div id="speakers">

          <a href="" id="seeall">EXPAND</a>
          <a href="" id="seeall2">COLLAPSE</a>


            <div id="pics-wrap">
 content...
            </div>
</div>
```

PLEASE SEE THIS http://jsfiddle.net/ajinkyax/mSjbV/
ITS WORKING NOW.
SOLUTION : I removed extra space from SCRIPT tag

Comment: ur code has no problem... it works fine..

Comment: what is your jquery version ? and which browser are you testing ?

Comment: I'd rather check that jquery is linked correctly to the document.

Comment: In your website, you have some extra characters at the end of your: `$(document).ready(function(){ });&#8203;` If you see just blank space, don't mind about that, remove any empty space after that closure `});`

Comment: @Lollero THANKS MATE, yes my code was correct from beginning but it was not working cus of that extra space code. YOUR FIX worked :)

Comment: By the way... Firebug console for the win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#seeall2").hide();

    $("#seeall").bind("click", function () {
        $("#speakers").animate({
            width: 880
        }, 1500);
        $("#seeall").hide(500);
        $("#seeall2").show(500);
    });

    $("#seeall2").bind("click", function () {
        $("#speakers").animate({
            width: 410
        }, 1500);
        $("#seeall").show(500);
        $("#seeall2").hide(500);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guSvZ/1/)

Comment: Always nice to see a quick fix ;)

Answer (score 0):

The complete working page....

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="seeall" value="Show" type="button">
    Show</button>
<button id="seeall2" value="Hide" type="button">
    Hide</button>
<div id="speakers" style="display: none">
    [Your Content]
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#seeall2").hide();
        $("#seeall").bind("click",
                function (e) {
                    $("#speakers").show().animate({ width: 880 }, 1500);
                    $("#seeall").hide(500);
                    $("#seeall2").show(500);
                });
        $("#seeall2").bind("click",
                function (e) {
                    $("#speakers").hide().animate({ width: 410 }, 1500);
                    $("#seeall").show(500);
                    $("#seeall2").hide(500);
                });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

you are using two `anchor tags`

when you click on one `anchor tag` .  both

```
 $("#seeall").bind("click", and   $("#seeal2").bind("click",
```

events are triggerd .

try using two `buttons` instead of `anchor`

```
<input type="button" id="seeall" value="EXPAND" />
<input type="button" id="seeall2" value="COLLAPSE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

just try to add

```
  e.preventDefault();
```

in both click event

See Here : http://jsfiddle.net/mSjbV/2/